# how to add a json array response to a recycler adapter class from fragment

Tags: android, json, model-view-controller, android-recyclerview

my response from the json is getting good but i cant add this to my model class

my fragment class

```
    public class Premiums extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerPremium;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailslist = new ArrayList<>();
private PremiumAdapter premiumAdapter;
private PremiumDetails premiumDetails;
private JSONObject jsonobject;
private Context context;

public Premiums() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.premium_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerPremium = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_premium);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerPremium.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerPremium.setHasFixedSize(true);
    context = getContext();
    // premiumAdd();
    data();
    premiumAdapter = new PremiumAdapter(context, premiumDetailslist);
    recyclerPremium.setAdapter(premiumAdapter);
    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

private void premiumAdd() {
    PremiumRequestHandler premiumHandler = new PremiumRequestHandler("premiumADD");
    premiumHandler.executeAsStringRequest(new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response);

            JSONArray jsonarray = null;
            try {
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Log.e("id", String.valueOf(jsonobject.getInt("id")));
                        premiumDetails = new PremiumDetails(jsonobject.getInt("id"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("userid"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("mobile"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("cityid"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("price"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("comments"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("created"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("categoryid"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("MainCategoryID"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("views"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("ImageCount"),
                                jsonobject.getInt("storeid"),
                                jsonobject.getString("title"),
                                jsonobject.getString("default_photo"),
                                jsonobject.getString("CityName"),
                                jsonobject.getString("CategoryName"),
                                jsonobject.getString("currency"),
                                jsonobject.getString("description"));
                        premiumDetailslist.add(premiumDetails)
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            premiumAdapter.setPremiumDetails(premiumDetailslist);

        }
    }, new BaseRequest.ErrorResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exception) {

        }
    });


}

private void data() {
    PremiumDetails featuredDetails = new PremiumDetails(1, 2, 98555555, 15, 156, 1456789, 2, 2, 45, 78, 24, 5,
            "الدول العربية الواقعة في المشرق العربي في جنوب", "https://cdn.bezaat.com/th100x100_1471645516-71.jpeg", " احتلت أراضيه وذلك", "hell",
            "gragyt", "الشمال البحر الأسود وجورجيا ومن الشرق أرمينيا وإيران ومن الجنوب العراق وسوريا والبحر المتوسط مع حدود بحرية مع قبرص، ومن الغرب بحر إيجة واليونان وبلغاريا. هي عضو في منظمة التعاون الاقتصادي للبحر الأسود. تركيا دولة علمانية ديمقراطية، وحدوية، جمهورية دستورية ذات تراث ثقافي قديم. أصبحت تركيا متكاملة على نحو متزايد مع الغرب من خلال عضويتها في منظمات مثل مجلس أوروبا وحلف شمال الأطلسي، وغيره. وقد عززت تركيا أيضًا علاقات ثقافية وثيق"
    );
    premiumDetailslist.add(featuredDetails);

    featuredDetails = new PremiumDetails(2, 2, 98555555, 15, 156, 1456789, 2, 2, 45, 78, 24, 5,
            "الدول العربية الواقعة في المشرق العربي في جنوب", "https://cdn.bezaat.com/th100x100_1471645516-71.jpeg", " احتلت أراضيه وذلك", "hell",
            "gragyt", "الشمال البحر الأسود وجورجيا ومن الشرق أرمينيا وإيران ومن الجنوب العراق وسوريا والبحر المتوسط مع حدود بحرية مع قبرص، ومن الغرب بحر إيجة واليونان وبلغاريا. هي عضو في منظمة التعاون الاقتصادي للبحر الأسود. تركيا دولة علمانية ديمقراطية، وحدوية، جمهورية دستورية ذات تراث ثقافي قديم. أصبحت تركيا متكاملة على نحو متزايد مع الغرب من خلال عضويتها في منظمات مثل مجلس أوروبا وحلف شمال الأطلسي، وغيره. وقد عززت تركيا أيضًا علاقات ثقافية وثيق"
    );
    premiumDetailslist.add(featuredDetails);

    featuredDetails = new PremiumDetails(3, 2, 98555555, 15, 156, 1456789, 2, 2, 45, 78, 24, 5,
            "الدول العربية الواقعة في المشرق العربي في جنوب", "https://cdn.bezaat.com/th100x100_1471645516-71.jpeg", " احتلت أراضيه وذلك", "hell",
            "gragyt", "الشمال البحر الأسود وجورجيا ومن الشرق أرمينيا وإيران ومن الجنوب العراق وسوريا والبحر المتوسط مع حدود بحرية مع قبرص، ومن الغرب بحر إيجة واليونان وبلغاريا. هي عضو في منظمة التعاون الاقتصادي للبحر الأسود. تركيا دولة علمانية ديمقراطية، وحدوية، جمهورية دستورية ذات تراث ثقافي قديم. أصبحت تركيا متكاملة على نحو متزايد مع الغرب من خلال عضويتها في منظمات مثل مجلس أوروبا وحلف شمال الأطلسي، وغيره. وقد عززت تركيا أيضًا علاقات ثقافية وثيق"
    );
    premiumDetailslist.add(featuredDetails);}}
```

my adapter class

```
    public class PremiumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PremiumAdapter.MyViewHolderPremium> {
private List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

public PremiumAdapter(Context context, List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList) {
    this.premiumDetailsList = premiumDetailsList;
    this.context = context;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
public void setPremiumDetails(List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList) {
    this.premiumDetailsList = premiumDetailsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class MyViewHolderPremium extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    private TextView txtTitle,txtDescription,txtCityName,txtPrice,txtCategory,txtHour,txtPhotoNo;
    private NetworkImageView imgPhoto;
    public MyViewHolderPremium(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_fad);
        txtDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_fad);
        txtCityName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_name_fad);
        txtPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_fad);
        txtCategory = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_fad);
        txtHour = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_fad);
        txtPhotoNo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_no_fad);
        imgPhoto=(NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo_lod_fad);
    }
}

@Override
public MyViewHolderPremium onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.featured_ad_adapter_layout,parent,false);
    final MyViewHolderPremium myViewHolderPremium = new MyViewHolderPremium(itemView);
    return myViewHolderPremium;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolderPremium holder, int position) {
    PremiumDetails premiumDetails = premiumDetailsList.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(premiumDetails.getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(premiumDetails.getDescription());
    holder.txtCityName.setText(premiumDetails.getCityName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(Integer.toString(premiumDetails.getPrice()));
    holder.txtCategory.setText(premiumDetails.getCategoryName());
    holder.txtHour.setText(Integer.toString(premiumDetails.getCreated()));
    holder.txtPhotoNo.setText(Integer.toString(premiumDetails.getImageCount())+" photos " );
    try {
        imageLoader= VolleyHandler.getImageLoader();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    //imageLoader.get(featuredAddDetails.getDefault_photo(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imgPhoto, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));


    holder.imgPhoto.setImageUrl(premiumDetails.getDefault_photo(),imageLoader);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("size", String.valueOf(premiumDetailsList.size()));
    return premiumDetailsList.size();
}}
```

but when i try to add through data method it is getting in my recycler otherwise it is getting getitemcount in adapter as zero
json response is getting ,plz help me

my Json Response

```
    [{"id":15105820,"userid":2469720,"mobile":"01222303389","title":"\u0645\u0637\u0644\u0648\u0628 \u0634\u064a\u0641 \u0645\u0634\u0627\u0648\u064a \u0648 \u062c\u0632\u0627\u0631 ","default_photo":"","CityName":"\u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0629","CategoryName":"\u0641\u0646\u062f\u0642\u0629 \u0648\u0645\u0637\u0627\u0639\u0645","cityid":37,"storeid":null,"price":0,"currency":"\u062c\u0646\u064a\u0647","comments":1,"created":"1473429996","categoryid":448,"MainCategoryID":80,"description":"\u0645\u0637\u0644\u0648\u0628 \u0644\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644 \u0628\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0629 \u0645\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0647 \u0644\u0639\u062f\u0629 \u0645\u0637\u0627\u0639\u0645 \u0643\u0628\u0631\u064a\r\n- \u0634\u064a\u0641 \u0645\u0634\u0627\u0648\u064a \u0648 \u062c\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0647 \r\n\u0634\u0631\u0637 \u0623\u0633\u0627\u0633\u064a: \u064a\u0634\u062a\u0631\u0637\u00a0\u0627\u0644\u062e\u0628\u0631\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0645\u062c\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0637\u0627\u0639\u0645 \u0627\u0648 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0646\u0627\u062f\u0642\r\n\u0627\u0644\u0631\u062c\u0627\u0621 \u0623\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a: fb.restaurant@outlook.com\r\n ","views":9292,"ImageCount":0},]
```

Comment: Please post your json data sample.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray.length(); j++) Why tou are running two loops? Once if you have taken JSONObject outside then remove the second loop

Comment: @Preetika edited ,remove for loop

Comment: is it working now? Put a log and check what is count you are getting for jsonarray length

Comment: @Preetika count is 9

Comment: @JoseAntony have you tried my solution

Comment: @RahulKhurana i tried it is not working

Comment: @PreetikaKaur when i trying to call data method it is adding to adapter why i cant add by calling premiumadd()

Comment: @JoseAntony you have null records in you json response please check if jsonparsing is not breaking at any instance.See if there is any exception

Comment: @Preetika yes my json is some time giving no value at default_image,and in Store_id ,what i have to do

Comment: remove null from your record due to exceptions you are facing this problem or if it cannot be done from service end so you have to check whether the object you are fetching is null or not if not null then perform the logic if null then set some default value at your end

Comment: @PreetikaKaur i solved thank you thank you very much i set some values and now i got the result

Comment: uh great can I post it as answer if it helps you accept it and upvote it @JoseAntony

Comment: @PreetikaKaur yes thank you

Comment: @JoseAntony done kindly accept and upvote it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON contains some null responses. Get those null values removed.
Before setting it to your **PremiumDetails** POJO give a check if object value is null or not if null then set any default value at your end while parsing. For example

```
 if(jsonobject.getString("title").equals(null)){
    // set any default value 
}else{
    // set the value from json response
}
```

**Note**: Make sure not to include any null record while parsing that will break the flow and excption will occur. Glad to help...

Comment: reputation is less for me

Comment: no issues try it later if you remeber it now your reputation is 8

Comment: sure i will when i reached my reputation i will

Comment: Glad to help you.. Cheers your prob is solved you ned to make 15 reputation to upvote anyone's answer

Answer (score 0):

after adding  `premiumAdapter.setPremiumDetails(premiumDetailslist);` you need to call `premiumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: yes but it cant be done because already we getting json object

Comment: @JoseAntony you edited your question and it totally changes the style of parsing

Comment: i changed because already we are getting a JSONobject at jsonobject

Comment: @JoseAntony i changed my answer. Please check and let me know

Comment: i check that too but it is not working it get item count is showing zero

Comment: you need to call **premiumAdd();** at last in onCreateView() method because it getting reset again